# data loading to qlikview extension this.Data

Tags: qlikview

I'm trying to use extension for Qlikview 11SR2.

I've tried to access data with this.Data.Rows, but this object is empty even though the data is not empty and I can display the data in a table.

The code I have used is:

```
var obj = this.Data;

for(var prop in obj) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "" + prop + "" + obj[prop];
    this.Element.appendChild(div); 
}
```

I have no access to the internet - I work offline.

How can i make this.Data.Rows contain the data (it is undefined)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your feedback, I would say it might be worth trying a slightly different way of accessing your data as the `this.Data.Rows` object contains a collection of row objects which in turn contain one or more objects, which relate to the dimensions and measures passed to the script (and are defined in `definition.xml`).

For example, say that I have an extension that features a dimension and a measure (in that order). I can access each value of these in a loop as follows:

```
for (var rowIx = 0; rowIx < this.Data.Rows.length; rowIx++) {
   var row = this.Data.Rows[rowIx];
   myDimensionValue = row[0].text;
   myMeasureValue = row[1].text;
}
```

I can then add code to output each value of `myDimension` and `myMeasureValue` to the loop, such as in your case adding a new `div` for each set of values.

I found the "QVConsole" extension invaluable when writing extensions, as it allows you to have a JavaScript console in your QlikView document, so you may then use statements like `console.log(myDimensionValue)` etc. to help you debug your extension. You can download it from https://github.com/thomasfriebel/QvConsole.

Comment: I think that my definition.xml file is well defined, how can i be sure?

Comment: I'm accessing this.Data.Rows in this code :  
  
var obj = this.Data;  
for(var prop in obj) {  
 var div = document.createElement("div");  
 div.innerHTML = "**" + prop + "**" + obj[prop];  
 this.Element.appendChild(div);  
}  
  
The value printed in rows is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In you extension object in the webview, set the dimension and a valid expression.  Let me know whether it works!